Infinite linear combination: conditions for not escaping the source space
Let $\mathbf{y}=\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in an
infinite-dimensional Lebesgue space $L^{p}(\mathsf{\Omega},\mathcal{F}
,\mathrm{P})$, $p\geq1$, on some probability space $(\mathsf{\Omega
},\mathcal{F},\mathrm{P})$. For any sequence of real numbers $\mathbf{a}
=\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, we say $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}$ converges
to $Y$ in $L^{p}$, written $Y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}=\mathbf{a}
^{\prime}\mathbf{y}$, if
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}Y_{n}\overset{L^{p}}{\rightarrow}Y\in L^{p}\text{ as
}N\rightarrow\infty
$$
We make the following assumptions

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert Y_{n}\right\vert $ converges in $L^{p}$,
thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}$ converges in $L^{p}$ for any
$\mathbf{a}\in\ell^{\infty}$.

$\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is linearly independent, thus
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}=0\iff a_{n}=0\text{ for all }n
$$


Let
$$
\mathsf{Y}=\left\{  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}:\mathbf{a}\in\ell^{\infty
}\right\}  \subseteq L^{p}
$$
and define a continuous linear function $f:\mathsf{Y}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
such that $v_{n}=f(Y_{n})>0$ for each $n$, and $\mathbf{v}=\{v_{n}
\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\in\ell^{1}$.
My question: for any sequence $\{a_{n}\}$, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert
a_{n}\right\vert v_{n}<\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}\in L^{p}$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert v_{n}<\infty\implies\left\Vert
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}\right\Vert <\infty
$$
where the $\left\Vert Y\right\Vert =\operatorname{E}\left(  \left\vert
Y\right\vert ^{p}\right)  ^{1/p}$ is the $L^{p}$-norm. Prove it or find a counter-example.
If it is not true, what additional restriction on the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is needed?

What I have done:
Let the vector space $\mathsf{V}$ be a sequence space such that for any
$\mathbf{a}=(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n},\cdots)\in\mathsf{V}$, we have
$$
(a_{1}v_{1},a_{2}v_{2},\cdots,a_{n}v_{n},\cdots)\in\ell^{1}
$$
Endowed with the $V$-norm
$$
\left\Vert \mathbf{a}\right\Vert _{V}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert
a_{n}\right\vert v_{n}
$$
the normed vector space $(\mathsf{V},\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{V})$ is a
Banach space.
In a financial market with infinitely many assets, the continuous linear
function $f$ is a pricing function. Let $a_{n}$ be the number of units of
asset $n$ held, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}$ is a financial portfolio
defined by an infinite linear combination. The holding $\mathbf{a}\in
\ell^{\infty}$ keeps the portfolios in $L^p$, I like to extend the holding to a larger space, like
$\mathbf{a}\in\mathsf{V}$.

No. Here is a counterexample:
Let $(\Omega, P)$ be s.t. $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ and $P = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} \delta_n$ (effectively the counting measure - I’m adding the $2^{-n}$ weights to ensure it is a probability measure). Consider $L^1(\Omega, P)$. Let $Y_n = e_n$. Then indeed they are linearly independent in the strong sense you wrote down, and $\sum_n |Y_n|$ indeed converges.
Let $f: L^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f((x_n)) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n}\frac{1}{n^3}x_n$. One easily observes that this is a continuous linear functional (in your formulation, you asked for $f$ to be defined on $\mathsf{Y}$, so simply restrict the above to $\mathsf{Y}$). We also have $v_n = f(Y_n) = 2^{-n}\frac{1}{n^3} > 0$ and $(v_n) \in \ell^1$. The sequence $a_n = 2^n n$ satisfies,
$$\sum_n |a_n|v_n = \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$$
But $\sum_n a_nY_n$ does not converge in $L^1$. Indeed,
$$\|\sum_{n = 1}^N a_nY_n\|_{L^1} = \|\sum_{n = 1}^N 2^n ne_n\|_{L^1} = \sum_{n = 1}^N n \to \infty$$

I don’t really know what to say regarding additional constraints to put on $a_n$ to ensure convergence. Really, there’s no reason to expect any one fixed linear functional (or any finitely many, for that matter) will be able to tell you whether $\sum_n a_nY_n$ converges in $L^p$.
